# How to properly "hold down" a multi-key "toggle looping this" hotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm encountering a specific problem. Know when you hold down a key, and after a moment it repeats? It essentially does that, in the middle of holding both keys down. My questions are first, how I would properly make a "toggle command" hotkey with multiple-key combos. Second, how to turn off this repeating issue.
An example of code that has both issues:

;Purpose: Delete a lot of useless stuff very quickly.

```
^R::
    SetKeyDelay, 10 ;default
    Send, {Del}{Enter}{Down}
    while GetKeyState("R","P")
    {
        Send, {Del}{Enter}{Down}
        Sleep , 100 ; 50 or so
    }
    Return

Return
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure from your description, but doesn't the below do what you want?

```
^R::
    SetKeyDelay, 10 ;default
    Send, {Del}{Enter}{Down}
    while GetKeyState("R","P")
    {
        Send, {Del}{Enter}{Down}
        Sleep , 100 ; 50 or so
    }
    KeyWait, R
return
```

Note: I tested it in windows explorer, and only with `Send, {Del}{Down}`. The `KeyWait, R` waits for you to release your 'R' key, thus the hotkey isn't fired multiple times but once.

Ref: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm